# IIS7 HTTP Redirect - Change Site1 Content and Removes Site2 Redirect

Tags: http, iis-7.5, redirect

We had two sites setup in IIS7.5 for a long time.  They were named (not real name but you get the point)....

"domain.com" and "www.domain.com"

The purpose was to set "HTTP Redirect -- Redirect requests to this destination" setting to "http://www.domain.com" and checkbox == true.

Last week I applied Windows Updates to our server.  Now when changing the "Advanced Settings --> Physical Path" in the www.domain.com site it unchecks the above setting for HTTP Redirect in domain.com site and we drop to a 403.

I need to know if this is by design or a bug introduced by the service pack or updates.  Please help!  I can send screen shots or whatever to help describe.

Updates applied are:

- KB2584146
- KB890830
- KB2631813
- KB2644615

Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

If both sites share the same physical path, they also share configuration by design.

Configure the physical path of the "domain.com" site to some empty folder on which the "Anonymous" identity (`IUSR` by default, otherwise the application pool identity) has access to read and execute, and then reconfigure your http redirection rule to redirect all requests to http://www.domain.com/